# Славянские языки

Tags: лингвистика

А вот интересно, какой из славянских языков на сегодняшний день ближе всего к истинно славянскому (ведь многие языки, тот же русский, сильно подверглись влиянию западных языков)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все одинаково далеки. Сравнивать невозможно, да и сам термин "славянский" совершенно ненаучен. Есть понятие праславянского, есть не всеми признанный протославянский, иногда рассматривают древнеславянский как промежуточный от праславянкого к "общеславянкому" в момент его разложения, но это все достаточно пустые разговоры. "Эталонного" славянского, с которым можно было бы сравнивать, просто не существует.
За таковой можно взять исторический церковнославянский (очень близкий к древнерусскому, хотя отличия есть), он же (почти) - древнеболгарский, но это уже период прогрессирующего разложения общеславянской языковой общности, на общеславянский он никак не может претендовать. Общеславянский (или поздний праслявянский) язык мог существовать не позднее V века нашей эры (дальше уже пошло расселение славян, положившее начало языковому разложению), но мы почти ничего не знаем о языке той эпохи.

Answer (score 0):

На это вопрос ответ дала ДНК-генеалогия. Генетически носителями славянского праязыка она называет носителей гаплогруппы R1a1. К данной гаплогруппе относятся восточные славяне и поляки. Южные славяне имеют гаплогрупу I2, болгары - R1b1. Иными словами, все они принадлежат к другим человеческим родам, когда-то говорившим на своих, отличных от праславянского языках и перешедших на впоследствии на славянский. Таким образом, именно русский язык является прямым наследником древнего славянского языка. Польский таковым быть не может по причине сильного влияния латыни, как священного языка католической церкви.
А церковно-славянский (древне-болгарский) язык был лишь диалектной разновидностью древне-русского со своими национальными особенностями, отсутствием склонения существительных, и наличием таких красивых параллелей общих существительных, как брег вместо берега, брада вместо бороды ит.д., придающих литературному слогу высокий стиль.

Comment: >На это вопрос ответ дала ДНК-генеалогия. Генетически носителями славянского праязыка она называет носителей гаплогруппы R1a1. 

Читали эти последние Гарвардские исследования по генетике? Это очень интересно (я без иронии, серьёзно пишу). НО (!) мне кажется нельзя их (ДНК-генеалогию) совершенно прямо соотносить с филологией. Чтобы не вдаваться в дебри -- простой пример. Человек может быть носителем этой *теоретически* праславянской гаплогруппы R1a1, но при этом говорить на каком-то жутком диалекте весьма далёком от праславянского языка.

Comment: Генетика -- тело человека, а филология -- речь человека!

Если почитаете внимательно первоисточник, то увидите, что миллионы людей с R1a1 живут в Северной Индии, и генетически являются потомками переселенцев из Восточной Европы. Разве их язык -- САМЫЙ близкий к праславянскому? Подчёркиваю -- САМЫЙ.

Comment: А я и не говорил, что язык Северной Индии самый близкий к праславянскому. Я сказал, что русский язык - самый близкий к праславянскому. А генетика с филологией, на самом деле, тесно связаны. Тело русского человека, как правило, говорит на русском языке.

Comment: Я согласна с @Nikolja. Сначала надо четко отделить "генетически русского" человека от других. Что маловероятно ввиду давности. Возражение @Евгений61 нелогичное.

Comment: Эк, куда Вас занесло. Так Вы скажете, что и русских как народа не сущесвует.Эту песню я слышу постоянно. Вам русское тело русским языком отвечает, а Вы отрицаете ему в праве на существование. Даже обидно.
Вот гаплотип русского человека - 13 25 16 10 11 14 12 12 10 13 11 30 15 9 10 11 11 24 14 20 32 12 15 15 16. Почитайте Анатолия Клёсова, он профессор гарвардского университета и занимается этой темой. Всё в открытом доступе.

Comment: И ещё не поленитесь. Поинтересуйтесь данными Русской антропологической экспедиции 1956-1959г.г. под руководством В.В.Бунака. Очень авторитетный антрополог. Русские существуют и являются народом гомогенным, т.е. однородным. Антропологические параметры занимают центральное положение в ряду европейских, т.е. в какой-то мере эталонными. Чаще, чем в Европе встречаются светлые газа,светлые волосы, чуть больший процент людей со светлой кожей.  

А по поводу человека гаплогруппы R1a1 говорящем на весьма далёком от праславянского языка, то есть и такие, например, киргизы.

Comment: >Я согласна с @Nikolja. Сначала надо четко отделить "генетически русского" человека от других.  
  
Это все можно сделать. Принцип отделения общего от частного еще никто не отменял. Только я никак не пойму, а зачем?! Здесь идёт жуикая подмена представления о генетическом родстве **народов** родством **языков**. С таким же успехом можно было объявить родсвенниками всех людей, носящих одинаковую одежду.

Comment: @behemothus, Вы правы. Я вообще не хочу больше отвечать этому типу. У него тараканы в голове, так что бесполезно.

Comment: Ответ попахивает расизмом...

Comment: Чей ответ? Я уже было такое подумал...

Comment: "Здесь русский дух, здесь Русью пахнет..."

Comment: Я - русский человек с русским самосознанием. Мой язык - славянский и корни его в глубокой древности. Он не упал с неба вчера. У него были предки. Русские обдадают определёнными антропологическими признаками. Что же вы мне тут ярлыки навешиваете. Docenti вообше ничего не поняла из моего комментария. 
Ответ мой на заданный вопрос был таким: Русский язык, являясь прямым потомком древнего славянского и похож на него больше других. Вот и всё!

Comment: >Я - русский человек с русским самосознанием  
>Docenti вообше ничего не поняла из моего комментария  

Второе вытекает из первого.

Comment: >Русский язык, являясь прямым потомком древнего славянского и похож на него больше других.

Похож, конечно же похож. Русский похож на древнеславянский в какой-то степени, я согласен.

Вот не хотел я эту дискуссию продолжать, но уж напишу пару слов. Такой вопрос. А Вы, **Евгений61**, знаете ещё хоть один другой славянский язык кроме русского, чтобы сравнивать? Вот хотя бы немного?

Вы будете удивляться, но крайне правые (т.е. националисты) из, пожалуй, любой славянской страны заявят совершенно безапелляционно, что именно ИХ язык -- САМЫЙ-САМЫЙ!

Comment: Возьмём, для спокойствия, кого подальше (чтобы ещё с ними не спорить), к примеру, хорваты. Такие пуристы, что все иностранные слова стараются заменять словами со славянскими корнями. Футбол -- ногомет, индикатор -- показивач и т.п.

У меня есть старинное Евангелие на церковно-славянском. Там язык довольно сильно отличается и от современного русского и, например, современного украинского и т.п. Но попадаются слова похожие или одинаковые с современными русс. и укр. языками.

Comment: И, конечно же, в славянских языках существуют слова дошедшие без изменений (или с малыми изменениями) ещё из праиндоевропейской старины. Например, "снег" и мн.др. Вы удивитесь, но весьма древние слова есть и в литовском, и в греческом, и в санскрите. Это не есть тайной и списки ПИЕ (праиндоевропейских) слов и корней для соответствующего языка можно найти в Интернете и ознакомиться с ними.

Comment: Я, конечно, не генетик и не лингвист. Я математик. Мне довелось соприкасаться со статистикой, и со статистической геномикой, так что представляю себе "кухню", в которой варятся теории. Серьезный ученый всегда будет осторожен в выводах, т.к. понимает, что они условны и зависят от метода. Ну, а несерьезный всегда может "поиграть" на идеях, на саморекламе.  
Кроме того, мне, живущей в Татарстане как-то странно слышать, что русские - генетически однородный народ. Тем более, что в наше время большая часть татарского народа тоже является русскоязычной (впрочем, в недавно по историческим меркам).

Comment: Одно радует. На улицу эти *расовые фошысты* aka *поцреоты* пока не суются и предпочитают тайно гадить на форумах... Другого способа обратить на себя внимание у них нет.

Comment: Думаю, здесь может быть просто недостаток ума. "Простые" теории всегда легче принять: это - черное, это - белое. А то еще в оттенках разбираться придется...